# $\ell^p(J)$ is complete (Banach)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I have to prove that the space

$\ell^p(J)$ defined as the set of all functions

$\psi: J\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$

s.t. $\psi$ is null except in a contable subset of $J$

and

$||\psi||_p :=\bigg(\sum_{t\in J}|\psi(t)|^p\bigg)^{1/p}<\infty$

is Banach (complete).

Well, given a Cauchy sequence $(\psi_n)_n\subset \ell^p(J)$ I defined $\psi$ such that each $\psi(t)$ is defined as $\lim \psi_n(t)$ (each of these sequences $\psi_n(t)$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{F}$).

I proved that $\psi_n\rightarrow \psi$ and $||\psi||_p<\infty$. However, I could not prove that $\psi$ is null except in a contable subset of $J$.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $\psi(t) \ne 0$, then some $\psi_n(t) \ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, for $n$ bigg... But combining various $n$'s biggs, I could not prove yet the result. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe because intersection/union of contable sets are contable?

Comment: A secondary doubt: a non-contable sum can be finite?

Comment: The union of countably many countable sets is countable.

Comment: $ \psi (t) \neq 0 \implies \psi_n (t) \neq 0 $ to $ n $ big enough. Thus, where $ J_n $ is the subset of $ J $ with zero measure out of which $ \psi_n$ cancels, the points on which $ \psi $ does not vanish are contained in the enumerable union $ \cup J_n $, also measure null... Is it correct? Many thanks.